# Make custom field sortable in list

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-admin

I have my custom field like this:

```js
import { Typography } from '@mui/material'
import { PublicFieldProps, sanitizeFieldRestProps, useRecordContext } from 'react-admin'
import Files from 'types/Files'
import { formatFileNumber } from 'utils/client'

interface FileNumberFieldProps extends PublicFieldProps {}

const FileNumberField = (props: FileNumberFieldProps) => {
  const { ...rest } = props
  const record = useRecordContext<Files>()

  return (
    <Typography component="span" variant="body2" {...sanitizeFieldRestProps(rest)}>
      {record.FileNumber ? formatFileNumber(record.FileNumber) : ''}
    </Typography>
  )
}

FileNumberField.displayName = 'FileNumberField'

export default FileNumberField
```

I use this in a standard `List` component, which I want to allow for sorting by this field. The built-in fields like `TextField` can be clicked on, but my custom one not. I tried already to specify it explicitly with:
`<FileNumberField label="File-Nr." sortable={true} />`

What do I need to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably also need to specify name of the sort field `sortBy` (because your component does not use the `source` property):

```
<FileNumberField label="File-Nr." sortable={true} sortBy="FileNumber" />
```

[Writing Your Own Field Component](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#writing-your-own-field-component)

Comment: Thanks! I just added these settings as default props in the `FileNumberField.tsx` so that I don't have to repeat them all the time: `FileNumberField.defaultProps = { sortable: true, sortBy: 'FileNumber' }`